# Spring Data JPA repository keep connection open in a request

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, connection, spring-data-jpa

my problem is a bit complicated to explain, but basically seems that there some relation between my number of active connections and the delay to get some data from a remote server (web service). I mean I have a query to get some data in the database and after that a I do a call to this webserver, but everytime the latency of this webservice increase my connection in the database start to increase as well. I'm using Spring data jpa and Spring Boot.

Comment: elaborate the question with your coding example and the exact issue.

Comment: Show some code with measurements and exact description what you measured. So long I won't believe that calling a web service has an effect on the performance of the database.

Comment: I think that the problem is spring.jpa.open-in-view, but I'm not sure if it keep the Database connection as active.

Comment: Hi @ThiagoHora, did you find the root cause of the issue? I'm experiencing something similar with the same setup